# isset - else inside an array used to create a form

Tags: php, arrays

Hi how to write correctly an isset->else in an array used to create a form?

For example:

```
$this->form[] = array(
    'surname' => (isset($vars['sur_name']) ? $vars['sur_name'] : '')        
);
```

I want to put `else -> 'surname' => $current_user->user_lastname`

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ternary condition act as a IF...ELSE condition

```
$this->form[] = array(
     'surname' => (isset($vars['sur_name']) ? $vars['sur_name'] :  $current_user->user_lastname)      
);
```

is the same thing as

```
if (isset($vars['sur_name']){
   $this->form[] = array('surname' => $vars['sur_name']);
}
else {
   $this->form[] = array('surname' => $current_user->user_lastname);
}
```

[read about ternary operator here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)